# Unicode characters in the txt file read incorrectly

Tags: java, encoding

I have a `txt` file which contains some Unicode characters like

```
\u0070\u0075\u0062\u006C\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0063\u006C\u0061\u0073\u0073\u0020\u0020
\u0055\u006E\u0069\u0063\u006F\u0064\u0065\u0020\u007B\u0020\u0070\u0075\u0062\u006C\u0069\u0063
\u0020\u0020\u0073\u0074\u0061\u0074\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0020\u0076\u006F\u0069\u0064\u0020\u0020
```

I'm using `java.util.Scanner` to read this text file on a Solaris environment. I haven't specified any encoding for the file. Now when I print the scanned contents, I see the Unicode characters just like above. I don't see the actual characters represented by these Unicode characters.
Can you please let me know what is the reason that it reads the contents like this?

Comment: Those are unicode escapes. They make sense within String literals. In a file, they are just regular characters.

Comment: But in properties file if I have these Unicode escaped characters, it is read properly. Are these both different?

Comment: Perhaps the properties loader parses them in a special context that considers them as unicode.

Comment: Is it possible to read the content properly (language characters also there) without specifying the encoding type to java.util.Scanner? Does it treat .txt files differently from others. The same code works fine in Windows environment.